# laravel variable from blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass an object from my index page to a function and I am trying to differntiate between servers + domains, I can do this on the index page by getting the class name however the variable passed to my function is only the id so I can not see if the object is a server or domain,

**if i try and do this it sends the whole object as variable ($invoice):**

```
        {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => array('InvoiceController@bill', domains.'/'.$invoice))) !!}
```

**controller**

```
public function index() {
    $expiry = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+3 months'));
    $servers = Server::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
    $domains = Domain::where('expiry_date', '<', $expiry)->orderBy('expiry_date', 'asc')->get();
    $invoices = $domains->merge($servers);
    return view('invoices.index', compact('servers'))->with(compact('domains'))->with(compact('invoices'));
}
```

**form**

```
 <tbody>
            @foreach($invoices as $invoice)
            <?php $reflect = new \ReflectionClass($invoice); ?>
            {!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'POST', 'action' => array('InvoiceController@bill', $invoice))) !!}

            <tr>
                @if ($reflect->getShortName() == 'Domain')
                <td><a href="{{ route('domains.show', $invoice->id) }}">{{ $invoice->id }}</a></td>
                @endif
                @if ($reflect->getShortName() == 'Server')
                <td><a href="{{ route('servers.show', $invoice->id) }}">{{ $invoice->id }}</a></td>
                @endif
                <td>{{ $invoice->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->expiry_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $reflect->getShortName() }}</td>
                <td>{{ $invoice->ClientName }}</td>
                <td>
                    @if ($reflect->getShortName() == 'Domain')
                    {!! link_to_route('domains.edit', 'Edit', array($invoice->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
                    @endif
                    @if ($reflect->getShortName() == 'Server')
                    {!! link_to_route('servers.edit', 'Edit', array($invoice->id), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) !!}
                    @endif
                    {!! Form::submit('Bill', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) !!} </td>

            </tr>

            {!! Form::close() !!}

            @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

**controller**

```
public function bill($invoice) {


    $invoice = Domain::whereId($invoice)->first();

    $bill = new BilltoKashflow();
    $bill->bill($invoice);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more understandeable.

Comment: @GinoPane what doesnt make sense so i can change it

Comment: What do you mean with "differentiate `$domain` and `$server`"?

Comment: @barfoos I need to know if the object is a Server or Domain, which are 2 objects that I have merged into the $invoice variable

Comment: Please add the PHP tag to your question. This allows for syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to your controllers via `route parameter`, `GET` or `POST`.

If you decide to use the `route parameters`, you can automaticly bind a model. See [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-model-binding)

***Edit:***

If your `Form-Open` tag looks like this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-inline', 'method' => 'POST', 'route' => array('handle-bill', domain->id, $invoice->id))) !!}
```

The corresponding route should look like this:

```
Route::post('/bill/{domain}/{invoice}', [
    'as' => 'handle-bill',
    'uses' => 'InvoiceController@bill'
]);
```

How the model binding has to look depends on your laravel version

Comment: so if i wanted to bind 2 models(domain/server) to a route how would i do that?

Comment: take a look at the link in my answer ;)

Comment: change it the way i have written